# inner join-where-order by-limit in mysql

Tags: mysql

*When I am executing mysql query with **limit 0,50** . I am getting 50 rows.*

```
SELECT md.*,cl.country_name FROM master_detail md
INNER JOIN country_list cl on cl.country_value=md.Partner_value
where md.for_country_value='577' order by md.id LIMIT 0,50
```

*But When I am executing mysql query with **limit 50,100** . I am getting 100 rows.*

```
SELECT md.*,cl.country_name FROM master_detail md
INNER JOIN country_list cl on cl.country_value=md.Partner_value
where md.for_country_value='577' order by md.id LIMIT 50,100
```

*Actually I want data on the basis of limit?* **what will execute first where or limit or order by?**

Comment: what this query is for.??? what is the main reason for using this query.?

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter in LIMIT is where it should start fetching records and the second one is how many. So 50, 100 : start at row 50, get 100 records.

[LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
limit 50,100
```

can rewrite as

```
limit 100 offset 50
```

means in the limit clause first parameter is be offset and second is be actual limit.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing the what you are expecting. You should not change the second parameter if you need to get 50 records. Let it by 50. Change first parameter every time. It tells the starting point.

```
SELECT 
    md.*,
    cl.country_name 
FROM master_detail md
INNER JOIN country_list cl 
    on cl.country_value=md.Partner_value
WHERE md.for_country_value='577' 
ORDER BY md.id LIMIT 50,50
```